# How to uninstall openldap?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, openldap

How can i uninstall OPENldap from linux? I had problems with the initial configuration of openldap with the domain or how can i change the configuration of the ldap domain?

Comment: How did you install it? rpm, apt-get, yum?  Use the same command to remove it.  Also you ask two questions - which do you want an answer for? Uninstall or fix

Comment: Preferble to know how to fix it, but also im not very sure in the correct way of uninstalling it, so i think it will be nice to know the correct way.

Comment: @uSlackr It is flagged Mint, so apt then.